# Reset the value by clicking using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in my calendar dates and time slots are showing. In the header month name will be shown and dates will be shown below as a list. After selecting a date time slots will come. Also, selected date will be shown with MonthName while displaying time slots. Now, if you click on MonthName (in the header) in time listing page, then dates of that month will be shown by replacing times. Suppose, you go to Nov and select 01 Nov, then in the header it will show 01 Nov 2015 and time slots will be displayed below. Now again click on the header (01 Nov 2015), dates of Nov will be shown. But I want to remove the date that is 01 from the MonthName header while showing the dates from time page. Somehow, I need to reset the selected date value from MonthName header when it is coming back to display dates from time page. Below is the code of getting Month Name and I have added plunker below.

```js
var date = new Date();
    var months = [],
        monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var tempMonth;
    tempMonth = date.getMonth();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        months.push(monthNames[tempMonth] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
        tempMonth += 1;
        if (tempMonth >= 12) {
          tempMonth = 0;
          date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
        }
    }
    $scope.year = 2015;
    $scope.changeMonth = function(steps) {
        if ($scope.monthIndex + steps >= 0 && $scope.monthIndex + steps <= 12) {
            $scope.dateValues = [];
            $scope.monthIndex = $scope.monthIndex + steps;
            $scope.monthName = $scope.months[$scope.monthIndex];
            var date = new Date();
            console.log(date.getMonth());
            var offset = date.getMonth()
            console.log($scope.monthIndex);
            var offsetDate = offset + $scope.monthIndex;
            $scope.nDays = new Date($scope.year, offsetDate + 1, 0).getDate();
            console.log(offsetDate + 1);
            console.log(new Date($scope.year, offsetDate, 1));
            for (i = 1; i <= $scope.nDays; i++) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var displayDate = new Date($scope.year, offsetDate, i);
                if (displayDate >= d) $scope.dateValues.push(displayDate);
            }

        } else {
            console.log("missed")
        }
    };

    $scope.monthIndex = 0;
    $scope.months = months;
    $scope.monthName = months[0];
    $scope.changeMonth(0);
```

Plunker Link :- http://plnkr.co/edit/35UwiYLEqv3LYY6RiL1q?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate the custom month value selected by the user, and the one displayed when clicking the title.

You should replace the ng-click with a function.

```
<h3 class="text-center" ng-click="clickMonth()"> {{selectedMonthName}} </h3>
```

And in your js:

```
$scope.clickMonth = function (){
$scope.selectedMonthName = $scope.monthName;
$scope.showType = 1;
}
```

Also update your selectDate() function:

```
 $scope.selectedMonthName = $filter('date')(date, 'dd MMM yyyy');
```

And your changeMonth() function:

```
 $scope.selectedMonthName = $scope.monthName;
```

[Plunkr right here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mD06lK0bhDp97Kp9TNQ?p=preview)

Comment: Okay. Your plunker link not attached yet.

Comment: Sorry about that, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the following way:

```
$scope.changeShowType = function (type) {
  $scope.showType = type;
  $scope.monthName = $filter('date')($scope.selected.date, 'MMM yyyy');
};
```

and in your index.html change the line to this:

```
<h3 class="text-center" ng-click="changeShowType(1)"> {{monthName}} </h3>
```

This way a function will be executed when you click, giving you more options to do something when the header is clicked.